# Can I have a static route like this in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action, routes

In my web application I will have a route like :

```
http://server/requests/info/{id}-{guidPart} (a string)
```

So I thought Id be clever and make a route so I did :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Info",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}-{guidPart}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Requests", action = "Info", id = 0, guidPart = "" }
);
```

Then I thought, why do I need to specify defaults, why not have it all fixed except the last part :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Info",
    url: "requests/info/{id}-{guidPart}"
);
```

But when I go to a url like  :

```
http://server/requests/info/123-abc123
```

It fails and says :

**404 Resource not found.**

Any tips on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a static route, but you still have to specify which Controller and Action to route to by default.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Info",
url: "requests/info/{id}-{guidPart}",
defaults: new { controller = "Requests", action = "Info", id = 0, guidPart = ""});
```

The difference between this and the defaults above is that this UriTemplate will only try to match a Uri starting with "requests/info/"

Comment: Either way, if you don't have a matching controller/action, it will return a 404

Comment: Thanks, so it means that if I specify fixed values in the `url` it will be better for performance and that is the main reason for having such a possibility?

Comment: The initial template is the default UriTemplate and it's flexible to handle any controller/action combination.  I don't think performance is an issue here.